I am getting error while running pandas on leetcode
Original error was:
PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
  * The NumPy version is: "1.25.0"
  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from ""
Please note and check the following:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
installed.
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
numpy:
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
    raise ImportError(
Line 16 in <module> (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py)
    import pandas as pd
Line 1 in <module> (_driver.py)
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 3 of 4: Resource temporarily unavailable

I am getting this error while running  pandas code on leetcode IDE
I checked numpy and datetime modules on my vscode are working fine. What can I do now?

Welcome to SO! We'd probably need more information on how you installed each component of your environment. In parallel, there are a number of github reports matching the error you report (e.g. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19528), so be sure to check those if you haven't already.

Make sure to add up to 5 relevant tags, necessarily Python but also e.g. OpenBlas, python-import, importerror. Right now only people watching the tag pandas may find your question.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

We'd probably need more information on how you installed each component of your environment. In the meantime:

First, a dummy check: would you have a script named 'datetime.py' by any chance ? Your solution just might be as simple as that Python3 numpy import error PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"
Then, a number of github reports match the error you report, so be sure to check those if you haven't already, .e.g.:

PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime" #19528,
In the contect of HPC this is likely relevant for you: ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime" - Resource temporarily unavailable #14474


Finally, consider using Anaconda to handle your environments for you

